# Is there a way to extend user plgin in octoberCMS in production

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I'm asking if there's any way to extend user plugin in OctoberCMS by adding more fields when the site is already in production. I know how to do this in development but I don't know how to do it i production. Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just create new plugin in development which is going to extend your user plugin.

fields you are going to add just write them in to `update files` -> `plugins\hardiksatasiya\demotest\updates`

```
1.0.1:
    - 'Initialize plugin.'
1.0.2:
    - 'Created table hardiksatasiya_demotest_'
    - update_user_my_custom_add_seen.php
```

> `update_user_my_custom_add_seen.php` file

```
<?php namespace HardikSatasiya\DemoTest\Updates;

use Schema;
use October\Rain\Database\Updates\Migration;

class UpdateUserMyCustomAddSeen extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function($table)
        {
            $table->timestamp('last_seen')->nullable();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function($table)
        {
            $table->dropColumn('last_seen');
        });
    }
}
```

> this example shows how to add `last_seen` field in `users` table

now just use extend api to add field in form `extendFormFields` https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#extend-form-fields

now test them on development server if all is working fine.

> then only put that plugin in `plugins` directory
>
> directory structure => `plugins \ < author name > \ < plugin name >`
>
> now in live system - from backend `logout` and `login`

i guess this will do all required stuff.

> **make sure you test plugin well in development. to avoid unwanted problems**

if any doubts please comment.